# php session file deadlock

Tags: php, linux, deadlock

In fixing a website for someone, I've run into the following problem:

In order to process some data, it calls `exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php input.dat")`, while the `file.php` that gets called contains an `include("config.php")`, which, in turn, contains a call to `session_start()`.

The problem that occurs is a deadlock waiting for `flock("/tmp/sess_XXXXXX")`. The parent script locks the session file, then the `exec`'ed script attempts to continue the same session, locking that file again, but getting deadlocked waiting for it.

I've tried putting the following at the very beginning of the the `exec`'ed script, but to no avail:

```
session_save_path("/tmp/alt_session");
session_id("NOTHING");
```

Obivously there's something distinctly absurd about calling `exec("php ...")` from within a php script, but that's an argument for another day, and not something I can change here. Also, while I'm free to change the file that gets run under `exec`, changing `config.php` would create a some other headaches that I'd prefer to avoid.

Any other options, or am I missing something important?

Comment: Do you need a session opened in parent script? If no - you could `session_write_close()` right before you call child with `exec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is a php bug that I believe relates to your problem.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42064)

In short, the solution was to run `session_write_close()` before `file_get_contents()`, (which in your case would be `exec()`)